# Combining KVC Collection Operators

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, cocoa-touch, kvc

Is it possible to combine KVC collection operators in iOS? Something like:

```
[someManagedCollection valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.@count.objects"];
```

Right now, I'm doing it like this:

```
[[someManagedCollection valueForKeyPath:@"distinctUnionOfObjects.objects"] count];
```

but I'm wondering if combining operators would lead to better performance.

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see for yourself?

Comment: Well I know it doesn't work, but didn't know if there was something missing in structure or implementation

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be brief, but in my experience, "No." (And yes, I've tried.)